# Weird characteristic polynomial question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $F_A:\,\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})\to\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$ be defined by $\mathrm{M}\mapsto \mathrm{MA}+\mathrm{AM}$. I am doing a question which asks me to write the characteristic polynomial of $F_A$ in terms of trace and determinant of $A$.

**Attempt:**

They suggested I start with $\mathrm{A}$ diagonal. Not knowing how to deal with the matrix space, I decided to treat it as a map $\mathbb{C}^4\to\mathbb{C}^4$. If $\mathrm{A}=\text{diag}(\alpha,\beta)$ then $F_A$ is represented by $\text{diag}(2\alpha,\alpha+\beta,\alpha+\beta,2\beta)$.

Then using $\text{tr}\,F_A=4(\alpha+\beta)$ and $\det F_A=4\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)^2$ I computed the polynomial and got:

> $$\text{char}_{F_A}(x)=x^4-\text{tr}\,F_A
>  x^3+\left(\frac{5}{16}\left(\text{tr}\,F_A\right)^2+4\frac{\det
>  F_A}{(\text{tr}\,F_A)^2}\right)x^2-\left(8\frac{\det
>  F_A}{\text{tr}\,F_A}-\frac{(\text{tr}\,F_A)^3}{32}\right)x+\det F_A$$

... which looks *ridiculous*, and weirdly complicated given the relatively nice map. So I'm guessing something's wrong in my interpretation of the question, but I'm not sure what? Could someone offer a little help?

Comment: You can start representing $F_A$ as a matrix itself. How do you do this for any other linear transformation? See its action on basis vectors. What are the basis vectors in $M_2(\Bbb{C})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $A$ is similar to $B$, i.e. $A = S B S^{-1}$ with $S$ invertible, then $F_A(M) = M S B S^{-1} - S B S^{-1} M = S (S^{-1} M S B - B S^{-1} M S) S^{-1} = S F_B (S^{-1} M S) S^{-1}$, so $F_A$ and $F_B$ are conjugate and thus will have the same
characteristic polynomial.  I'll use the basis $e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}$ of $M_2(\mathbb C)$, where $e_{ij}$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $1$ and the others $0$.

Case 1. Suppose $A$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $d_1, d_2$.  Then the matrix for $F_A$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $2d_1, d_1+d_2, d_1+d_2, 2d_2$, and the characteristic polynomial is 
$$(\lambda - 2 d_1)(\lambda - 2 d_2) (\lambda - (d_1+d_2))^2 = (\lambda^2 - 2 \text{tr}(A) \lambda + 4 \det(A))(\lambda - \text{tr}(A))^2$$

Case 2. A dense set of $4 \times 4$ matrices are diagonalizable, and the characteristic polynomial, trace and determinant are  continuous functions of the matrix, so the formula from Case 1 must be true for all $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Gah I see where I went wrong: I was writing it in terms of $\text{tr}\,F_A$ an $\det F_A$ when instead they meant $\text{tr}\,A$ and $\det A$, as you have done. Hence the horrible result. Thanks.